# Infinite series of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, summation

Find Value of  $$S=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$$

$$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4n+4}}$$

But here i cannot express above sum in form of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \times \sum_{r=1}^{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the interval $r\in[n^2,(n+2)^2]$ the terms $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$ have a quite small variation: they are approximately all equal to $\frac{1}{n}$; since there are $4n+5$ terms, the limit is expected to be $\color{red}{4}$. 
In a more rigorous way,
$$ \frac{4n+5}{n+2}\leq \sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \leq \frac{4n+5}{n} $$
and the previous claim follows by squeezing.

Comment: Awesome sir thank you so mcuh

Answer (score 2):

As you already wrote $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=n^2}^{(n+2)^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$,
$$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+4n+4}}$$

When you take $n^2$ common out from the square root then your eq. becomes:

$$S=\frac{1}{n}\lim {n \to \infty}[1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt(1+ \frac{1}{n^2})}+......+\frac{1}{\sqrt(1+\frac{2}{n})^2}]$$

Can  you solve from here?